# Why does disqus display same comment for different pages?

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I am trying to integrate the `disqus` and `angular.js` together.

I found [this useful directive that I can use](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus).

Disqus is successfully loaded except same comments for all pages.

I have set the `disqus-identifier` to a guid. So it should be unique.

Can some one help me on this?

Comment: It sounds like you are setting it to the same value for every page. Disqus-identifier must be unique for each page.

Comment: Hi Mike, the Disqus-identifier is unique. I checked that. As I said in the post, they are all Guid.

Comment: I was asking for clarification because it wasn't clear: "*a* guid. So *it* should be unique" made it sound like there was only one guid, which would cause your problem. More code/details would help. From what you described, it's possible that 1) all your URLs are the same and no disqus-id is being set (or it is being set after disqus has loaded), or 2) the URLs are different but each disqus-id is the same.

Comment: every Guid is unique and url is unique as well

Comment: Ok thanks. It sounds like then maybe the angular placeholder is there on disqus load so it sees it as the same id every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working [Angular Disqus plugin](https://github.com/kirstein/angular-disqus).

Add this attr directive in view

```
<div disqus="e.id"></div>
```

Then

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngDisqus']); // add module

window.disqus_shortname = 'YOUR_DISQUS_SHORTNAME'; // define disqus shortname
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus cuts urls if it is too long or too complicated.
Try to simplify your URLs (reduce `/`)